# PHP help me parsing array

Tags: php

```
Array (
    [items] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [webContentLink] => https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-8ZjfWGsMOwbkg0RkdLZ0lpbzA&export=download
            [title] => 08. Devil Fish Dumpling.mp3
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [webContentLink] => https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-8ZjfWGsMOwckVzMXFwNDJTN3c&export=download
            [title] => 06. electro peaceful.mp3
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [webContentLink] => https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-8ZjfWGsMOwQWVlSHRiRDV0RVU&export=download
            [title] => 02. FRIENDSHIP.mp3
        )
        [3] => Array (
            [webContentLink] => https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-8ZjfWGsMOwbURlQ3U2VUFuSWs&export=download
            [title] => 03. polygon.mp3
        )
        [4] => Array (
            [webContentLink] => https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-8ZjfWGsMOwLXVGM1dKV1BjUDA&export=download
            [title] => 10. HEAVENLY MOON.mp3
        )
        [5] => Array (
            [webContentLink] => https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-8ZjfWGsMOwSWo1N2NtR2FDTHc&export=download
            [title] => 13 Far east nightbird.mp3
        )
        [6] => Array (
            [webContentLink] => https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-8ZjfWGsMOwWUJMbXJ0V2JsanM&export=download
            [title] => 01 - Connect.mp3
        )
        [7] => Array (
            [webContentLink] => https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-8ZjfWGsMOwQ0lVYndpRXlpRnM&export=download
            [title] => 02 Don\\\'t cry.mp3
        )
        [8] => Array (
            [webContentLink] => https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-8ZjfWGsMOwMVl3WHRVenB4akE&export=download
            [title] => 01 nexus.mp3
        )
        [9] => Array (
            [webContentLink] => https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-8ZjfWGsMOwZVdmQnBXX1pnTEE&export=download
            [title] => 1-02 SEED.mp3
        )
        [10] => Array (
            [webContentLink] => https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-8ZjfWGsMOwNTZHTHV4TjYzZHM&export=download
            [title] => 1-01 Follow me.mp3
        )
    )
)
```

I need to parse this array.

Comment: Why are you unable to parse it? It already looks pretty parsed to me.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with that array..? and what have you already tried...?

Comment: Please read the FAQ and then try to reformat your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$links = array();
$titles = array();
foreach ($arr['items'] as $key => $item)
{
$links[$key] = $item['webContentLink'];
$titles[$key] = $item['title'];
}
for ($counter=0; $counter<count($links);$counter++)
{
echo 'The song has link: '.$links[$counter].'<br />Title: '.$titles[$counter];
}
```

Arrays **links** and **titles** will have all the information you need.

Comment: it stops first array.  [items] => Array < here

Comment: I meant you name your array as $arr.